# Photos that get uploaded are grouped together

Tags: facebook, publish, photos

One of my apps publishes a photo to a Facebook Timeline...  In the past, if someone posted a photo at different times during the day, they would appear as separate published items on the Timeline.

Now, however, it groups those photos all together.

Example:  I publish a photo, via an app, at 11am, 2pm, 5pm.

What used to happen:  Each photo would be posted separately.

What happens now:  They are all grouped together.  (5pm photo is displayed on the Timeline with the 11am and 2pm photos).

They are all going to the same album (which I want) - I just want them to appear separately.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are having the same issue.  Seems like there was a change in the last 2 weeks re: how fb treats photo's being posted via API.

Previously, anything posted an hour apart would be treated as independent posts. Now, we are observing grouping for content posted up to 5 hours apart.

Comment: Thanks Greg!  Sorry for the late reply!